# Компактность условия

Tags: c#, инспекция-кода

Как подобное условие можно сделать компактнее ?

```
    ...
    else if ((relativeRectangle.Y == 0 && relativeRectangle.X < rect.Width) || (relativeRectangle.Y == 1 && relativeRectangle.X < rect.Width) || (relativeRectangle.Y == 2 && relativeRectangle.X < rect.Width) || (relativeRectangle.Y == -1 && relativeRectangle.X < rect.Width) || (relativeRectangle.Y == -2 && relativeRectangle.X < rect.Width))
    {
       Cursor = Cursors.SizeNS;
    }
```

Comment: Уточните диапазон входной величины для `relativeRectangle.Y`.

Comment: @Rootware от -2 до 2 достаточно,с примером я разберусь.

Comment: Оно совершенно нечитабельно, его нужно наоброт разуплотнить. Как вариант — вынести в отдельную функцию. Читабельность важнее компактности

Comment: @andreymal вот дали ответ ниже, вроде всё читабельно и компактно.

Comment: +1 к мнению @andreymal. Напрашивается вопрос: что хотели сказать этим условием - и это как раз и будет названием нового метода.

Comment: @Vipz но я, например, всё равно не понимаю, что это условие делает. Возможно, я просто не знаю предметную область, но всё же это намекает на оставшуюся нечитабельность (A K дело говорит)

Comment: @andreymal спасибо, буду иметь ввиду.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Так должно быть короче:

```
else if (relativeRectangle.Y >= -2 && relativeRectangle.Y <= 2 && relativeRectangle.X < rect.Width)
{
    Cursor = Cursors.SizeNS;
}
```

или так:

```
else if (Enumerable.Range(-2, 2).Contains(relativeRectangle.Y) && relativeRectangle.X < rect.Width)
{
    Cursor = Cursors.SizeNS;
}
```

Comment: Здорово! Спасибо.